# ayuda Servlet envio de parametros

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

estoy intentando que el valor que me recoge de la session iniciada me liste los alumnos en esta tabla pero no se como capturar ese valor
lo captura en value pero como lo capturo en el servlet? ya intente con el name="nIdeEmpresa" pero devuelve null
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Enviar el parametro en la pagina anterior

```
<a href="ClienteController?metodo=lista&nIdeEmpresa=<%=loginDTO.getnIdeArea()%>">Listar Clientes</a>
```

y recibirla en en servlet

Comment: ¿Es esto una respuesta?

Answer (score 0):

Según Veo hay varias cosas que puedes validar que pueden  impedir la recuperación de la data:
Lo primero en probar es utilizar un request y no un arrayList que seria la forma adecuda de recuperar los datos de la vista `jsp`

Te coloco un ejemplo:

```
    //Recuperacion Id empresa 
    int empresa = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter( "nIdeEmpresa" ));


    // Se instancia los recursos del modelo y se da respuesta al request
    // en esta parte validas el null (PARA ESTE CASO NO LO HAGO)
                     ClienteServise sr = new ClienteServise( );
                     ResultSet lista = sr.listaClienteServive( empresa );

   // Se guarda el resultado de la operación No es necesario el list si no lo vas a tratar en el  mismo servlet
   // Instancia un Request para re-dirigir la data
                  request.setAttribute( "lista", lista );


        // Redirecciona el flujo de ejecución hacia la vista jsp
        RequestDispatcher vista = request.getRequestDispatcher( "listaClienteEmpresa.jsp" );
        vista.forward(request, response);
```

En tu vista jsp lees el request que seria la forma apropiada de leer la data traida de la query.

En ejemplo seria:

```
            <%            
 //          <!--MOSTRAR LA CONSULTA  DE  BD-->
  ResultSet lista = (ResultSet)request.getAttribute( "lista" );
  if(lista != null){
      if( lista.first())
      {
          lista.beforeFirst();
              out.println("<br /><br />"
              + "<form method='post' action=''>"
              + "<div style='overflow:auto' id='table_wrapper'>"
              + "<table border ='2px' align='center' id='list'>"
              + "<caption align='center'> LISTADO CLEINTES </caption>"
              + "<thead>"        
              + "<tr>"                                                      
              + "<th>CLIENTE</th>" 
              + "<th>ID CLIENTE</th>"
              + "<th>DIRECCION</th>"
              + "</tr>"
              + "</thead>"); 

        while( lista.next( ) ){



            out.println("<tr>"
                    + "<td >" + lista.getString( 1 ) + "</td>"
                    + "<td >" + lista.getString( 2 ) + "</td>"
                    + "<td >" + lista.getString( 3 ) + "</td>");  
        } 


        out.println("</table>");
        out.println("</div>");
        out.println("</form>");
     %>
```

> > Seria bueno si copiaras el codigo para hacer pruebas; las imagenes dificultan poder hacer los ejemplos mas exactos.

Saludos!